# Scoreboard and testfor issues using commandblocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building on a map in Minecraft, where a player (myself for example) will press a button and his status changes into "The Player is ready for the game to begin".
So, press button -> `/scoreboard players set @p IsReady 1`

Now I want to test if the player is ready, so

Redstone clock -> `/testfor Untertreiberman[score_IsReady=1]`

The command block tells me that it can't find the player, but I'm there with a status of "IsReady 1".

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I edited your question to improve its readability and (hopefully) clarified it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `/testfor` command, you can't use specific usernames to test for people on the server/world.

When testing for people with your score `IsReady`, use:

`/testfor <selector(@p)>[score_IsReady=1]`

So when someone is near by the commandblock, it will return true only if someone has IsReady=1.